# AutoMapper with c# 2.0 syntax

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0, automapper

I'm trying to create a custom mapping with AutoMapper, but I can't use 3.0 syntax with lambdas. How would one convert this 3.0 code into 2.0 ?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyClass, MyDto>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName))
```

**Edit:**

Since there was no better solution, we are now using vs2008 on one workstation to make these mappings and build a dll. I hope it won't be long until we upgrade to vs2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Jimmy has mentioned in the comments that AutoMapper uses expression trees. That doesn't *immediately* rule out the possibility of using .NET 2.0 (you can use Mono's implementation of System.Core), but if you can't even using C# 3 you'll have to construct all the expression trees manually, which it going to be a huge pain.

Are you absolutely prohibited from using .NET 3.5 and C# 3?

Comment: It used to be possible to use LINQ in VS2005 - see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nsatheeshk/Linq06302006030119AM/Linq.aspx (not sure if this is still supported though)

Comment: I'm getting stuck on delegate(Bar opt) { return opt.MapFrom(... What is Bar, and howcome it has .MapFrom method?

Comment: @Morri: Bar would be whatever the type of "opt" is in the original lambda expression.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm using the tutorial from http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Projection&referringTitle=Configuration%20Validation , and it doesn't tell what type "opt" is.

Comment: @Morri: I suggest you get the code working in VS2008 (e.g. in the free Express version) which will let you experiment with it - and hover over the parameter to see its type.

Comment: @Jon

AutoMapper uses expressions for strongly-typed reflection, so you can't go the anonymous delegate route.  The ForMember method accepts an Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>>, not Func<TSource, TMember>.